# How can I delete old Jobs from Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have 2 jobs. One is new, the other is old.

I need to delete the old one, so that it gets removed from Grafana dashboard too.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on evgenyl's answer, the exact command would be something like:

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={job="name_of_old_job"}'
```

Replace name_of_old_job with the name of the job you want deleted.

Reminder that you need to have started prometheus with the --web.enable-admin-api flag

Comment: I get "400 Bad Request". Any idea why?
Started with --web.enable-admin-api

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately** I don't think that there is an endpoint that delete a specific job **directly**, but you can delete its series, In order to delete old Jobs series from **Prometheus**, you will have to enable [the administrative HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#http-api) within promethues or you will get the following error :

```
{"status":"error","errorType":"unavailable","error":"admin APIs disabled"}
```

first of all you will have to restart your `prometheus service` with this **option** [--web.enable-admin-api](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/prometheus/#:%7E:text=%2D%2Dweb.enable%2Dadmin%2Dapi)

or if you are using **docker compose** for prometheus as I do, pass it in the `command` section:

```yaml
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      - '--web.enable-admin-api'                               # << Like this
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    expose:
      - 9090
    networks:
      - monitoring
```

now you can work with **Prometheus API**, run this in order to get a list of all prometheus jobs that you have:

```bash
curl http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/job/values
```

```
{"status":"success","data":["blackbox exporter","blackbox-exporter","cadvisor","node-exporter","postgres-exporter","prometheus"]}
```

for example I want to delete the series of `blackbox-exporter`, all what I have to do is to run the following command, with changing the necessary fields, like host, port and job name.

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={job="blackbox-exporter"}'
```

Now the `blackbox-exporter` series have been deleted, but if you want to delete them entirely even from the disk, you will have to use this endpoint

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/clean_tombstones'
```

you might have to **wait** for a while, it might be up to 2 hours or even more in order to see that the job label has been deleted, since you deleted all its series, after that period you can run again :

```bash
curl http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/job/values
```

```
{"status":"success","data":["blackbox exporter", "cadvisor","node-exporter","postgres-exporter","prometheus"]}
```

no trace for `blackbox-exporter` anymore

notice that if you want to delete series of a certain job that contain a space on its name, you will have to replace the space with `%20`

let's say I want to delete the series of `blackbox exporter` job, here is what you will have to do:

```
curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={job="blackbox%20exporter"}'
```

note the `%20` in place of space  .

for more information refer to how to [Delete Series in Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#delete-series)

and here is a swagger version to visualise things: [/admin/tsdb/delete_series](https://stoic-kare-8f0c7d.netlify.app/#/TSDB%20Admin%20API/deleteSeriesPOST)

Answer (score 0):

To delete metrics from Prometheus, you need to use delete API.

> curl -X POST -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]=a_bad_metric&match[]={region="mistake"}'

Check [Deleting time series from Prometheus](https://www.robustperception.io/deleting-time-series-from-prometheus) post for more details..

Comment: I am using prometheus-net for my C# - application, so how can I remove the job/metric using that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete metrics - yes, but the question is about deleting jobs.

Answer (score -5):

```
cd /var/lib/prometheus/      ###enter into prometheus storage directory
grep -irl "Old job name" .   ###Find out the directory of old job
```

Delete that directories which all listed by the above `grep` command.

```
service prometheus restart
```

It will remove the particular old job from Prometheus. But in the Grafana dashboard if you put the last 5 mins time range you cannot able to see metrics related to that job and you can see those metrics in a 1-hour time range. Don't worry, gradually it will get removed from our normal time range which we use!!